# Google Apps Script Library nested function not found

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a library with the following code

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Generate Code')
      .addItem('iOS', 'generateIOS')
      .addItem('Android', 'generateAndroid')
      .addToUi();
}
```

and in a different file in the same library I have

```
function generateAndroid(){
  generateFile('Android');
}

function generateIOS(){
  generateFile('iOS');  
}
```

Now, I'm using the library in a script

```
function onOpen(){
 Library.onOpen(); 
}
```

But I get

```
Script function not found: generateIOS For more information, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)
```

If I create a `generateIOS` function in the script that's using the library, it works. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`generateAndroid()` and `generateIOS()` don't exist in the global namespace, they exist in the *library's* namespace. So when you add items to the UI which call "generateIOS" and "generateAndroid", the script tries to run them from the same context as `onOpen()` and fails to find them. Remember that `addItem()` takes a pair of Strings as parameters, so it's a pretty dumb function and doesn't know that you're referring to the "Library" functions instead of the global ones.

There are two possible solutions I see:

1) Add global functions that simply pass the function call along to Library.

```
// inside the global context
function generateAndroid(){
    Library.generateAndroid();
}
function generateIOS(){
    Library.generateIOS();
}
```

2) Try adding the Library namespace to the `addItem()` string (note: I have NO idea if this will even work but it's worth a shot.

```
.addItem('iOS', 'Library.generateIOS')
.addItem('Android', 'Library.generateAndroid')
```

Comment: For me solution #2 don't seem to be working, so #1 is a good alternative